# Find XPATH button from elements that share stem, python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, automation, element

I am trying to do the same as this blog post (https://tmonty.tech/create-an-automated-web-bot-with-selenium-in-python)in my university but I am struggling with it, as a complete noob. I wondered if anyone could quickly look at my problem. Basically, my University is organizing the bookings into a table format. As an example (below) I would like to book Spinning at 12:15 on Thursday 31st of March. The XPATH for the word Spinning is:

```
`//\*\[@id="booking-details"\]/tbody/tr\[7\]/td\[2\] and it's element is : \<td data-bind="text: name" class="name"\>Spinning\</td\>`
```

The XPATH for the Select button is:

```
//\*\[@id="booking-details"\]/tbody/tr\[7\]/td\[6\]/a and it's element is : <a class="btn primary-color select-booking" data-bind="attr: { 'data-id': id, 'data-start': start }" data-id="SWKPV9ON1SVO9QY" data-start="Thu Mar 31 2022 07:15:00 GMT+0000">SELECT</a>
```

I can't simply search for the time as Zumba and Spinning are both that time. There are multiple Spinning as well. But the Spinning I want and my button have the same beginning

```
/\*\[@id="booking-details"\]/tbody/tr\[7\]/
```

Do you know how I could find the beginning of the XPATH that matches both and use that to find the button? The table is dynamic and changes according to date and availability.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!![image]

I have tried the contains(text) function but can't get that to search for both activity and date

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of both the elements.

Comment: I managed to solve my problem with this: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody/tr/td[contains(text(), 'Spinning')]/../td[6]/a[@data-start='Thu Mar 31 2022 12:15:00 GMT+0000']")

Comment: Just answer your own question with a answer then.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem with this: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody/tr/td[contains(text(), 'Spinning')]/../td[6]/a[@data-start='Thu Mar 31 2022 12:15:00 GMT+0000']" in fact, i improved this with searching for day, class and time instead like this: ((By.XPATH,'//tbody/tr/td/span[contains(text(), "Wednesday")]/../../following-sibling::tr/td[contains(text(), "Spinning")]/../td[contains(text(),"17:15")]/../td[6]/a'))).click()